# How tweak bounds based on viewport on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to tweak map zoom for coordinates.

I want to extend bounds for all points inside viewport object.

I am trying to make it so:

```
bounds.extend(place.geometry.viewport)
```

But in debug I see that after this row execution bounds don't change.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bounds.extend takes a google.maps.LatLng as its argument, not a google.maps.LatLngBounds object, which is what place.geometry.viewport (probably) is.

To "add" a google.maps.LatLngBounds to an existing bounds, use [bounds.union](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

```
bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
```

Comment: Why here it is work?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: I don't see bounds.extend in that code.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.